# Running a Google Maps App on Android Target 2.3.4 produces a FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services

I have created an Android App that uses Google Maps.  I am using Eclipse and the activity layout xml is as follows.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <fragment
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

And here is the Activity class

```
 @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
 public class MapViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  static LatLng currentLatLng;
  LatLng currentLocation;
  private GoogleMap map;
  boolean firstPass = true;
  double currentLat;
  double currentlong;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_view);

    showCurrentLocationOnMap(); 
    try {
        showSheltersAndFuelStops();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
//This will change when SQL connection string is implemented.
private void showSheltersAndFuelStops() throws IOException {
    List<McDonalds> mcdList = new ArrayList<McDonalds>();
    List<Subway> subwayList = new ArrayList<Subway>();
    String subwayRoswell1 = "1307 N Main St, Roswell, NM, 88203";
    String subwayRoswell2 = "1701 W Second St, Roswell, NM, 88201";
    String subwayLC1 = "2001 E Lohman, Las Cruces, NM, 88001";
    String subwayLC2 = "2821 N Telshor, Las Cruces, NM 88011";
    String mcdonaldsRoswell1 = "720 N Main St, Roswell, NM, 88201";
    String mcdonaldsRoswell2 = "1804 S Main St, Roswell, NM, 88203";
    String mcdonaldsLC1 = "4810 Mesa Grande, Las Cruces, NM, 88012";
    String mcdonaldsLC2 = "571 Walton Blvd, Las Cruces, NM, 88001";

          Subway subway = new Subway(" 1307 N Main St, Roswell, NM, 88203", 1.58, 8.0);
    subwayList.add(subway);
    Subway subway1 = new Subway(" 1701 W Second St, Roswell, NM, 88201", 2.47, 12.0);
    subwayList.add(subway1);
    Subway subsLC = new Subway(" 2001 E Lohman, Las Cruces, NM, 88001", 147.99, 185.0);
    subwayList.add(subsLC);
    Subway subsLC1 = new Subway(" 2821 N Telshor Drive, Las Cruces, NM, 88011", 147.12, 200.0);
    subwayList.add(subsLC1);


    McDonalds mcdonalds = new McDonalds(" 720 N Main St, Roswell, NM, 88201", 1.08, 8.0);
    mcdList.add(mcdonalds);
    McDonalds mcdonalds1 = new McDonalds(" 1804 S Main St, Roswell, NM, 88203", 2.9, 12.0);
    mcdList.add(mcdonalds1);
    McDonalds mcdonaldslc = new McDonalds(" 4810 Mesa Grande, Las Cruces, NM, 88012", 143.2, 185.0);
    mcdList.add(mcdonaldslc);
    McDonalds mcdonaldslc1 = new McDonalds(" 571 Walton Blvd, Las Cruces, NM, 88001", 147.62, 200.0);
    mcdList.add(mcdonaldslc1);

    showFuelStops(subwayRoswell1);
    showFuelStops(subwayRoswell2);
    showFuelStops(subwayLC1);
    showFuelStops(subwayLC2);
    showShelters(mcdonaldsRoswell1);
    showShelters(mcdonaldsRoswell2);
    showShelters(mcdonaldsLC1);
    showShelters(mcdonaldsLC2);
}



private void showFuelStops(String location) throws IOException{
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());  
    List<Address> addresses;

    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    if(addresses.size() > 0) {
        BitmapDescriptor subwayBitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fillingstation);
        currentLat= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
        currentlong= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
        LatLng subLoc = new LatLng(currentLat, currentlong);
        Marker fuelMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(subLoc).icon(subwayBitmapDescriptor).title("Subway, " + location));

    }       
}

private void showShelters(String location) throws IOException{
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());  
    List<Address> addresses;

    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    if(addresses.size() > 0) {
        BitmapDescriptor subwayBitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.shelter);
        double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
        double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
        LatLng subLoc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(subLoc).icon(subwayBitmapDescriptor).title("McDonalds, " + location));

    }       
}

private void showCurrentLocationOnMap(){
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    SupportMapFragment mf= (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    map = mf.getMap();
    //map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    LocationListener ll = new Mylocationlistener();
    boolean isGPS = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPS){
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 10, ll);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_view, menu);
    return true;
}
/**
 *Mylocationlistener class will give the current GPS location 
 *with the help of Location Listener interface 
 */
private class Mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    private boolean zoomed = false;
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
            // ---Get current location latitude, longitude---

            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
            currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            currentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            Marker currentLocationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"));
            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 15));
            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            if (!zoomed) {
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12), 2000, null);
                zoomed = true;
            }
            if (!firstPass){
                currentLocationMarker.remove();
            }
            firstPass = false;
            Toast.makeText(MapViewActivity.this,"Latitude = "+
                    location.getLatitude() + "" +"Longitude = "+ location.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            //MapViewActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MapViewActivity.this, NoGPSLocActivity.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

}

When I run this on other versions of Android the App runs fine but on a Target of Android 2.3.4 I get this fatal exception.

[image: Fatal Exception]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting an error because you trying to use a `Fragment` on a Android system that don't supports `Fragment`s out of the box. to enable fragment support for this version of OS, you have to add a referece from your project to the `google-support-v4` library. and use the `SupportMapFragment` object in your xml instead of `MapFragment`. you activity would have to extend `FragmentActvitiy` and not an ordinery `Activity` as it's probably does now.

You can read more on how to add a `Google Map API V2` to you application with support for erliear OS versions in a blog post I wrote:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

**UPDATE:**

Please make sure that the following 3 selected jar files`(red)` are located in your Android Dependencies folder `(green)`:

[image]

Comment: Wow Emil, thanks for all the great info.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: did you read the guide?: "4. Another import we have to make in order to make our application work on
Operation system prior to API11 is to import the support library this can be done very easily
using Eclipse: Right-Click you project and choose “Android Tools” and then choose
“Add Support Library…”:"

Comment: Ok So I did that and my app is still crashing with a fatal exception I have changed the code above to reflect the changes.

Comment: I did change it Emil.  Look at the code above.  Also I do have Google Maps v2 on there as well.

Comment: show your class full code. did you changed the activity? and what is the current error?

Comment: Ok so the full Activity Class is there.

Comment: ok, the code looks normal. are you positive you are making the right imports? nad could you show me a screen shot of your dependecies folder in your project? you are still getting the same error? and did you refrenced google-map lib?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27200/discussion-between-mark-basler-and-emil-adz)

Comment: I tried changing this per your discussion Emil but this still didn't work.

Comment: I am able to import the libs into my workspace Emil but I cannot get the two play service jars to show up in the lib folder in the Package explorer per the instructions on the Google Maps instructions.

Comment: what do you mean by: " I cannot get the two play service jars to show up in the lib folder in the Package explorer"?

Comment: Yeah I had to go back and verify but apparently that is a bug with importing the google play services.  I had to create a dummy class as a workaround but that did end up being the issue Emil.  Thanks for all the help, you are awesome.

Comment: You welcome, @MarkBasler. Glad you figured it out. have a nice coding : )